# What is the opposite of indexOf?

Tags: javascript

What would be the opposite of .indexOf()? I used a regexp to find numbers in a string and now I want to add them together:

```
function getnum(str){
    var nums= str.match(/\d+/g);
    return //30+83//
 }
 getnum("sdsoi30adsd83")
```

Is there some sort of .charAt() equivalent for arrays I could use for this?

I'm sorry this is a very beginner question. I've been up all day coding and I realize the answer may be very obvious but I've looked all over devdocs.io to no luck.

Comment: If you want to hop into a certain field in an `array`, why don't you try `yourArray[x]`, where `x` is the position you are looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function getnum(str){
    var nums= str.match(/\d+/g);
    var total=0;
    for(var i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    {
        total+=Number(nums[i]);
    }
    return total;
 }
 getnum("sdsoi30adsd83");
```

Comment: Or `eval(nums.join('+'))`. :-O

Comment: @RobG I have been strongly discouraged at SO to not to use eval.

Answer (score 0):

For example char at 5th character is

```
"sdsoi30adsd83"[4]
```

which is "i"

Answer (score 0):

```
return nums.reduce(function(c, n) {
    return c + parseInt(n);
}, 0);
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/TyV3s/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ES5 map-reduce function for this problem.
Of course the for-loop solution works fine.

```
function getnum(str){
    var nums= str.match(/\d+/g);
    console.log(nums);
    return nums.map(function (str) {
        // convert to a Int array
        return parseInt(str);
    }).reduce(function (prev, curr) {
        return prev+curr;
    }, 0);
}
console.log('result=' +  getnum("sdsoi30adsd83"));
```

As to your original question, the opposite of `indexOf()` is indexing by `.` or `[]`.

```
var a = "sdsoi30adsd83";
a[a.indexOf('3')]; // = "3"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Methods